Gitlab-ci.yml in react native Android
I'm trying to write gitlab-ci.yml for my react native project, the command ./gradlew assembleRelease is working fine in local but failing when running same on gitlab.
The error is: compileDebugJava something I'll share it with more details once I'm with my laptop.
I tried npx react-native run-android --variant=stagingrelease this is giving another error i.e no device connected. Ji
